# The drop down option should display depending on the previous option

Tags: javascript, html

```
        Designation<br>
         <select><br>
            <option value="hod">HOD</option>
            <option value="principal">Principal</option>
          </select><br><br>

         Department<br>
          <select>
            <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
            <option value="biotech">Bio-Technology</option>
            <option value="chemical">Chemical Engineering</option>
            <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="civil">Civil Engineering</option>
            <option value="computerapp">Computer Applications</option>
            <option value="computerscience">Computer Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electricals and Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electronics and Communication Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Information Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Instrumentation and Electronics Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Management Studies and Research Center</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Medical Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Physics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Telecommunication Engineering</option>              
            <option value="CSE">Physical education and Sports Sciences </option>
        </select>
```

If i select HOD option the above department should display. But if i select option Principal the department option should not come(display). Javascript is a bit confusing and i would need help regarding this.

Comment: There is no HOD option.

Comment: I have edited the question. please do check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing is your question is not clear . And I'm assuming as per your previous comments you want to hide drop down box if principle option is selected in first drop down box. here is your simple  answer.

```html
         Designation<br>
         <select id="designation" onchange="showDropDown()"><br>
            <option value="hod">HOD</option>
            <option value="principal">Principal</option>
          </select><br><br>
        Department<br>
        <select id="pepartments">
            <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
            <option value="biotech">Bio-Technology</option>
            <option value="chemical">Chemical Engineering</option>
            <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="civil">Civil Engineering</option>
            <option value="computerapp">Computer Applications</option>
            <option value="computerscience">Computer Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electricals and Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electronics and Communication Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Information Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Instrumentation and Electronics Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Management Studies and Research Center</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Medical Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Physics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Telecommunication Engineering</option>              
            <option value="CSE">Physical education and Sports Sciences </option>
        </select> 
        
     <script type="text/javascript">
     function  showDropDown()  {     
       var seelecDsg = document.getElementById("designation").value;  
         if(seelecDsg == "hod"){
          document.getElementById("pepartments").style.display = 'block';
         }else{
          document.getElementById("pepartments").style.display ="none";
         }
     }


    
 </script>
```

Comment: always welcome , if you have any doubts please comment below.

Answer (score 0):

Blow this code:

```
<span id="dept" style='display:none'>Department</span>
    <br>
        <select id="hod" name="HOD">
            <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
            <option value="biotech">Bio-Technology</option>
            <option value="chemical">Chemical Engineering</option>
            <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="civil">Civil Engineering</option>
            <option value="computerapp">Computer Applications</option>
            <option value="computerscience">Computer Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electricals and Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electronics and Communication Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Information Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Instrumentation and Electronics Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Management Studies and Research Center</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Medical Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Physics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Telecommunication Engineering</option>              
            <option value="CSE">Physical education and Sports Sciences </option>
        </select>  
<script>
   document.getElementById("hod").addEventListener("change", function(){
      document.getElementById('dept').style.display = 'block'; 
    });
</script>
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/skko48hn/2/)

Comment: this is jquery...not javascript update the answer accordingly.see his question.

Answer (score 0):

try using **display** `block` and `none` to get it done.: add id to your select boxes to use this,`id's` will help identifying the select boxes `uniquely`.

```html
         Designation<br>
         <select id="designation"><br>
            <option value="hod">HOD</option>
            <option value="principal">Principal</option>
          </select><br><br>
        Department<br>
        <select id="pepartments">
            <option value="architecture">Architecture</option>
            <option value="biotech">Bio-Technology</option>
            <option value="chemical">Chemical Engineering</option>
            <option value="chemistry">Chemistry</option>
            <option value="civil">Civil Engineering</option>
            <option value="computerapp">Computer Applications</option>
            <option value="computerscience">Computer Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electricals and Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Electronics and Communication Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Information Science and Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Instrumentation and Electronics Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Management Studies and Research Center</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mathematics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Mechanical Engineering</option>
            <option value="CSE">Medical Electronics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Physics</option>
            <option value="CSE">Telecommunication Engineering</option>              
            <option value="CSE">Physical education and Sports Sciences </option>
        </select> 
        
 <script type="text/javascript">
   document.getElementById("designation").addEventListener("change", function(){
     if(this.value == "hod"){
      document.getElementById("pepartments").style.display = 'block';
     }else{
      document.getElementById("pepartments").style.display ="none";
     }
   });


    
 </script>
```